Is there any way to do mkdir in fluent-bit?
I'm using tag as a file path. So if there's no directory in that path, I want to have it created automatically.
But I can't find a way.
[OUTPUT]
    Name file
    Match *

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.8/pipeline/outputs/file
The above document says there is "Mkdir", but it was not actually available.
[error] [config] file: unknown configuration property 'Mkdir'. The following properties are allowed: path, file, format, delimiter, label_delimiter, template, and csv_column_names.

Is there any way?

Can you share your fluentbit version. This was added in 1.8 but not existing before. And pls share the config which  creates the failure above.
